# Update TestStand Socket Test status (Execution Annunciator) while test is running?

Tags: sockets, status, teststand

I am looking for a way to update the test socket test status (the color: Green, Yellow, Red etc) indicator while the test is running. What I am experiencing is that the red color would appear only at the end of the entire test sequence if any of the test steps fail. If any of the tests in any of the subsequences fail, I can see Red appear on the right side in status indicator for any particular steps however, I would like to know how to have the status of the Execution Annunciator updated during run time as opposed to at the end of the test. As the sequence execution pointer goes through various steps during it's hard to see what failed as the pointer moves to next step after execution. In sequences that run for a long period of time, I would like to know by looking at the socket status whether any of the steps failed rather than waiting till the end of the sequence.

I tried looking at the report but it scrolls down and makes it impossible to see if anything has failed so far...!

See the screenshot below:

[image]

Thank you,

Comment: Hello, Can anyone please provide an update on this request? Any Teststand expert?